# Producer Consumer Code Issue (seems Notify method does not release the lock inside loop)

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a producer consumer using wait and notify method. Producer thread that will put some value in the common container that is an array list. Now in the beginning if the Consumer thread got the lock on the list it will check the size of the list and if the size is 0 in that case it will goes into the waiting state. Now the Producer thread will put the first value inside the loop and calls the Notify method so now the Consumer thread should get the notification and consume the value. Again the producer thread should resume and starts the next iteration of the for loop but it is not happening. For loop inside the Producer gets executed first and then consumer code is running.

Please guide me what I am missing I have searched over the web a lot but finding more complex implementations.

**Producer.java**

```
package com.multithreading;

import java.util.List;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

public List<Integer> commonObject;

Producer(List<Integer> commonObject) {
    this.commonObject = commonObject;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (commonObject) {
        System.out.println("First Thread got the lock");
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            System.out.println("First Thread producing value");
            commonObject.add(i);
            System.out.println("First Thread notified");
            commonObject.notifyAll();
        }
    }

}

}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
package com.multithreading;

import java.util.List;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

public List<Integer> commonObject;

Consumer(List<Integer> commonObject) {
    this.commonObject = commonObject;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (commonObject) {
        System.out.println("Second Thread got the lock");
        if (commonObject.size() == 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Second Thread going into Waiting state");
                commonObject.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Second Thread Consuming Value");
            for (int i : commonObject) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

**ProducerConsumer.java**

```
package com.multithreading;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ProducerConsumer {
public static void main(String [] arg){

    List<Integer> sharedObject=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Producer producer=new Producer(sharedObject);
    Consumer consumer=new Consumer(sharedObject);
    Thread t1= new Thread(producer);
    Thread t2= new Thread(consumer);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}

}
```

Comment: Please post text that explains your code, your problem, and your question. Details that help us understand all matter a great deal.

Comment: Assume if Consumer thread got the lock on the list it will check the size of the list and if the size is 0 in that case it will goes into the waiting state.
Now the Producer thread will put the first value inside the loop and calls the Notify method so now the Consumer thread should get the notification and consume the value. 

Again the producer thread should resume and starts the next iteration of the for loop but it is not happening. For loop inside the Producer gets executed first and then consumer code is running.

Comment: Please [edit] and improve your question since the question text is more important than the comments. Also please go through the [help] and the [ask] to see how to best use this site.

Comment: For me, your code is working fine, just one piece of advise, you have produced all items with same shared lock and hence, consumer was not able to start consuming till all the items were produced. Ideally, consumer should start working as soon as producer has produced one item. Secondly consumed objects are never been removed from the list (I would prefer to use a queue here)

Comment: Thank you  Aman!  for your response can you please make the required adjustment at the producer end